# Insert a comment after an If command in an Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I've been trying to insert a comment right after an If clause in an algorithm using:

```
\begin{algorithm}                       
      \begin{algorithmic}
                \Statex                 
                \If {If-clause}
                \Comment {{\footnotesize Comment-1}}
                    Consequence 1 ;
                    \Else 
                        Consequence 2;
                \EndIf
                \Statex         
      \end{algorithmic} 
end{algorithm}
```

This gives me the comment after then and "Consequence 1" sticks after the comment. Is there a way to keep the comment and obtain a normal If-then in the right order?

Answer (score 1):

Add `\State` before "Consequence 1".